# Why I am getting nulls in my SQL query?

Tags: sql, null, pivot, pivot-table

Guys I am trying to use `PIVOT` in the SQL query and its working great with `WHERE` clause but am getting nulls in the result if I remove the `WHERE` clause from my SQL statement. I can't seem to understand why I am getting nulls as there are no nulls in my table at all.
I just want to display all the tickets generated.

**SQL Query (With WHERE clause)**

```
--TD
CREATE TABLE tblTicketDetail
(
    TicketID INT,
    IssuerName NVARCHAR(30),
    TicketDescription NVARCHAR(30)
)


--EN
CREATE TABLE tblEngineer
(
    EngineerID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Name] NVARCHAR(30)
)

--TE
CREATE TABLE tblTicket_Engineer
(
    TicketID INT,
    EngineerID INT
)


INSERT INTO tblTicketDetail (TicketID, IssuerName, TicketDescription)
VALUES(1, 'Saqib', 'qwerty keyboard')

INSERT INTO tblEngineer ([Name])
VALUES('Imran Khan'), ('Mubeen Khan'), ('Faraz Ahmed')

INSERT INTO tblTicket_Engineer (TicketID, EngineerID)
VALUES(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)

SELECT  TicketID, IssuerName, TicketDescription, [1], [2], [3]
FROM (
    SELECT TD.TicketID, TD.IssuerName, TD.TicketDescription, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TE.EngineerID) AS EngineerNo, EN.[Name]
    FROM  tblTicketDetail AS TD
        INNER JOIN tblTicket_Engineer AS TE ON TD.TicketID = TE.TicketID 
        INNER JOIN tblEngineer AS EN ON TE.EngineerID = EN.EngineerID 
    WHERE (TE.TicketID = 1)
) AS DT
PIVOT(MAX([Name]) FOR [EngineerNo] IN([1], [2], [3])) AS PT

DROP TABLE tblTicketDetail
DROP TABLE tblEngineer
DROP TABLE tblTicket_Engineer
```

***Picture of Reference :***

[image]

**SQL Query (Without WHERE clause - displays nulls)**

```
SELECT  TicketID, IssuerName, TicketDescription, [1], [2], [3]
FROM (
    SELECT TD.TicketID, TD.IssuerName, TD.TicketDescription, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TE.EngineerID) AS EngineerNo, EN.[Name]
    FROM  tblTicketDetail AS TD
        INNER JOIN tblTicket_Engineer AS TE ON TD.TicketID = TE.TicketID 
        INNER JOIN tblEngineer AS EN ON TE.EngineerID = EN.EngineerID 
) AS DT
PIVOT(MAX([Name]) FOR [EngineerNo] IN([1], [2], [3])) AS PT
```

***Picture for reference :***

[image]

Comment: It comes from your ROW_NUMBER() getting a different result set to work on. ROW_NUMBER() OVER is a window function so it'll calculate the row number based on the result of a query, and seeing as your WHERE makes a different query, you'll get a different ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen
I see so what should I do if I want to display all tickets?

Comment: Perhaps a partition by as per the answer below - depending on what you want to achieve. Do the select first to give you the right actual result - and then the pivot second.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Thank you for taking time out to answer my queries. `PARTITION BY` was all I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tricky to tell exactly what's going on (a useful debugging technique that you might be able to use is to comment out parts of the query, such as the `PIVOT` and do `SELECT *` to understand the before and after data), but I think you might want separate row numbers for each separate ticket. In which case you want `PARTITION BY` in your `ROW_NUMBER()` call:

```
SELECT  TicketID, IssuerName, TicketDescription, [1], [2], [3]
FROM (
    SELECT TD.TicketID, TD.IssuerName, TD.TicketDescription,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
             PARTITION BY TD.TicketID
             ORDER BY TE.EngineerID) AS EngineerNo,
          EN.[Name]
    FROM  tblTicketDetail AS TD
        INNER JOIN tblTicket_Engineer AS TE ON TD.TicketID = TE.TicketID 
        INNER JOIN tblEngineer AS EN ON TE.EngineerID = EN.EngineerID 
) AS DT
PIVOT(MAX([Name]) FOR [EngineerNo] IN([1], [2], [3])) AS PT
```